# How to check if HtmlService is running?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have been working on an application where I use the Google Apps Script HtmlService so I can create the UI in HTML. The application runs some code that is shared with an OnEdit function, and depending on where I run the code from I need to pass different parameters. Therefore, I need to detect if the code is intialized directly from a spreadsheet, or from the HtmlService UI.

I have tried to set the parameters depending on active spreadsheet, but if I do that I can only use the UI from a specific sheet - if I use it from any of the others unintentional stuff happens.

Here is an example of the code (undeclared variables are declared elsewhere):

```
function loanHistory(input){

  for(var i = 6; i >= 4; i--){
    var currentCell = loanHistorySheet.getRange(deviceRow, i)
    var valueToMove = currentCell.getValue();

    loanHistorySheet.getRange(deviceRow, i).offset(0, 1).setValue(valueToMove);
    currentCell.clearContent();
  }

  var currentlyBorrowed;

  if(activeSheet.getName() === 'Borrow/Hand in') {
    currentlyBorrowed = input;
  } else {
    currentlyBorrowed = input.value;
  }

  loanHistorySheet.getRange(deviceRow, 4).setValue(currentlyBorrowed);
}
```

In this example, instead of 'activeSheet.getName() === 'Borrow/Hand in'', I would like to have something like 'isHtmlServiceRunning'.

Is there any way I can detect if the HtmlService UI is open to prevent unintentional code from running? Otherwise, I might just have to separate the code completely.

Hope I made my challenge clear - thanks to anyone who can help!

Comment: [Privatize](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#private_functions) the shared component of the functions (you can still call directly from any function in the Apps Script project) and then write public wrappers that your `HtmlService` can target. The public wrappers would handle your argument verification.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I'm not a programmer as such, and maybe that's why I don't completely understand your suggestion. I have added some example code, and I was hoping you could specify how private/public wrappers can be used to prevent 'currentlyBorrowed' from being set to 'input.value' instead of 'input' when using the UI while on a "wrong" spreadsheet? Thanks again.

Comment: `function pubWrapper(args) { myPrivateImplementation_(args, true); } function myPrivateImplementation_(input, isFromPublicWrapper) { /** do the stuff */ }`

Comment: I appreciate your help, but I still don't get it. Where am I supposed to put that, and what's the "stuff" I'm supposed to do in those brackets? Do I need to put all my code in there? Or is it the 'if' statement? I still need currentlyBorrowed to be assigned to a value - how will it still be if I prevent HtmlService from accessing it?

Answer (score 0):

There is no explicit Apps Script support for your executing functions to determine the origin of their call. A simple method to "bake this in" for yourself, when it matters, is to separate your functionality into the interface and implementation.

From `HtmlService`, only "public" Apps Script functions in your project are accessible. Any ["private" function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#private_functions) is not **directly** callable, but can still be accessed if there is a public method that invokes it.

Thus, if your origin script were like this:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e) {
    doTheThing(e.value);
  }
}
function doTheThing(inputVal) {
  /** do stuff */
}
```

and your `HtmlService` UI calls `doTheThing` directly, i.e. `google.script.run.doTheThing(someVar);`, you might implement this separation as follows:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e) {
    actualDoTheThing_(e.value);
  }
}
function doTheThing(argFromHtmlService) {
  var realArg = < .... >;
  actualDoTheThing_(realArg);
}
function actualDoTheThing_(inputVal) {
  /** do stuff */
}
```

and your `HtmlService` UI would not need to be changed - you would still execute `google.script.run.doTheThing(someVar);`. On the server end, however, you have decoupled the implementation from the interface, and thus can communicate to your implementation the origin of the call.

If your computation of `realArg` should also be hidden from debugging in the `HtmlService` UI, you could instead send an additional argument and check for it in the implementation:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e) {
    actualDoTheThing_(e.value);
  }
}
function doTheThing(argFromHtmlService) {
  actualDoTheThing_(argFromHtmlService, true);
}
function actualDoTheThing_(inputVal, cameFromHtmlService) {
  if (cameFromHtmlService === true) {
    inputVal = < .... >;
  }
  /** do stuff */
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I used a method similar to this suggestion, just setting a variable when I run the script from HtmlService - I don't know why I didn't think of this myself :)